# Expectation and Cholesky Decomposition

Tags: normal-distribution, cholesky

Assume that the random vector $(X,Y)$ is (bivariate) normally distributed. Show that
$$ \Bbb E[X|Y=y]= \Bbb E[X]+ \frac {Cov[X,Y]}{Var[Y]}(y-\Bbb E[Y])$$

Also, 
$$ Var[X|Y=y]= (1-\rho^2) Var[X]$$

I know i should be converting these variables into standard normal and then using Cholesky decomposition to come up with independent standard normal, I am getting pretty close to the answer but, its not neat. I might have done something wrong, Can some one please lay out the first step to convert X&Y to standard normal?? Thanks so much

Answer (score 4, accepted):

By Cholesky decomposition, you can express the normal random variables $X$ and $Y$ in the form
\begin{align*}
Y &= E(Y) + \sqrt{Var(Y)}\, \xi,\\
X &= E(X) + \sqrt{Var(X)}\left(\rho \xi+\sqrt{1-\rho^2} \eta\right),
\end{align*}
where $\rho = \frac{Cov(X, Y)}{\sqrt{Var(X)Var(Y)}}$ is the correlation, $\xi$ and $\eta$ are two independent standard normal random variables.

Then,
\begin{align*}
E(X \mid Y) &= E\left(E(X) + \sqrt{Var(X)}\left(\rho \xi+\sqrt{1-\rho^2} \eta\right) \mid \xi \right)\\
&=E(X) + \rho \sqrt{Var(X)}\xi\\
&=E(X) + \frac{Cov(X, Y)}{\sqrt{Var(Y)}}\xi\\
&=E(X) + \frac{Cov(X, Y)}{Var(Y)}\big(Y-E(Y) \big).
\end{align*}
The computation for $Var(X\mid Y)$ is similar, specifically,
\begin{align*}
Var(X \mid Y) &=E\left((X-E(X\mid Y))^2\mid Y \right)\\
&=E\left( (X-E(X\mid Y))^2\mid \xi\right)\\
&=E\left(Var(X)(1-\rho^2) \eta^2 \mid \xi\right)\\
&=E\left(Var(X)(1-\rho^2) \eta^2\right)\\
&=Var(X)(1-\rho^2).
\end{align*}

Answer (score 3):

**Another approach**

$$f_{X|Y}(x,y)=\frac{f_{X,Y}(x,y)}{f_{Y}(y)}\tag 1$$
Set
$$u=\frac{x-\mu_X}{\sigma_X}$$
and
$$v=\frac{y-\mu_Y}{\sigma_Y}$$
we have
$$f_{X|Y}(x,y)=\frac{\frac{1}{2\pi\sigma_X\sigma_Y\sqrt{1-\rho^2}}\exp\left(-\frac{u^2-2\rho uv+v^2}{2(1-\rho^2)}\right)}{\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}\sigma_Y}\exp\left(-\frac{1}{2}v^2\right)}\\\qquad\qquad\qquad\qquad=\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi(1-\rho^2)}\sigma_X}\exp\left(-\frac 12\left[\frac{u-\rho v}{\sqrt{1-\rho^2}}\right]^2\right)\tag 2$$
Indeed
$$f_{X|Y}(x,y)=\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi(1-\rho^2)}\sigma_X}\exp\left(-\frac{1}{2}\left[\frac{x-(\mu_X+\rho\frac{\sigma_X}{\sigma_Y}(y-\mu_Y)}{\sigma_X\sqrt{1-\rho^2}}\right]^2\right)\tag 3$$
as a result
$$\mathbb{E}[X|Y]=\mu_X+\rho\frac{\sigma_X}{\sigma_Y}(y-\mu_Y)\tag 4$$
and
$$\text{Var}(X|Y)=\sigma_X^2(1-\rho^2)\tag 5$$

Comment: A nice elementary approach.

Comment: So thanks Gordon . Indeed your answer is so nice